# Manage Binding String for TextField in ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, textfield

Hi all I'm trying to work with `TextField` inside a `ForEach`

I'm having problems with the `binding` string that I have to put in the text `parameter` of the `textField`

I have a `Manager` class where I have 2 strings which should be the textField `binding` in the **ForEach**

```
class Manager: ObservableObject {    
    @Published var name: String = ""
    @Published var address: String = ""
    @Published var city: String = ""    
}
```

Now as you can see in the `struct Test: View` I do a **ForEach** on an array and return **3 TextFields** but I can't figure out how I can associate `@Published var name`, `@Published var address`, `@Published var city` in the **TextField** of **ForEach**

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
       VStack {
       ForEach(Info.infos.indices, id:\.self) { index in
            TextField("\(Info.infos[index].title)", text: ???? )
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Can anyone point me the correct way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

```
struct Info: Identifiable {
    var scalableTitle: String
    var description: String
    var icon: String
    let id = UUID()
}
extension Info {
    
    static let rows: [Info] = [
        Info(scalableTitle: "Text", description: "@Nome", icon: "doc.plaintext.fill"),
        
        Info(scalableTitle: "Text", description: "@Pro", icon: "graduationcap.fill"),
        
        Info(scalableTitle: "Text", description: "@Text", icon: "door.sliding.left.hand.open")
    ]
    
    static let preview =
        Info(scalableTitle: "Text", description: "@Test", icon: "doc.plaintext.fill") }
```

---

```
struct InfoRow: View {
    @Binding var textFieldText: String
    var info: Info
    private var isEmpty: Bool { textFieldText.isEmpty }
    private var activeColor: Color { isEmpty ? .orange : .accentColor}
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(info.scalableTitle)
                    .font(.comfortaa(.bold, size: .body))
                    .scaleEffect(isEmpty ? 1 : 0.9, anchor: .leading)
                    .foregroundColor(activeColor)

                TextField(info.description, text: $textFieldText)
                    .font(.comfortaa(isEmpty ? .regular : .bold, size: .body))
                    .padding(8)
            }
            .animation(.default, value: isEmpty)
            Image(systemName: info.icon)
                .foregroundColor(isEmpty ? .orange : .accentColor)
                .font(.title2)
        }
        .padding(16)
        .overlay {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke()
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        }
        
        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
    }
}
```

---

```
struct InfoView: View {
    var info: [Info] = Info.rows
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(info) { value in
                InfoRow(textFieldText: <#T##Binding<String>#>, info: <#T##RowInfo#>)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's **one** more code line to specify three `TextField`s instead of the `ForEach`. And counting the closing brace as one code line it's no extra line at all.

Comment: The published properties needs to be arrays but that would be a horrible solution with 3 arrays so rather create a custom type (struct) with the 3 properties and then have a published property in Manager that is an array of that custom type. Also, it's preferred to not use indices in a ForEach but rather to loop over the objects

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I see... your explanation would seem clear. May I ask you for a code example in response to my question to have a confirmation that I understand all your explanation?

Comment: I'll try to post a solution later, unless someone beats me to it :)

Comment: Watch Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: Looking at the first comment by @vadian again I wonder if I have misunderstood what you want to do here, does `Info.infos` only contain the titles of the text fields? Then it would make much more sense to follow the advice and completely skip the `ForEach` loop and just create 3 `TextField` objects (and then you can leave your Manager class as it is).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `Info`  is **identifiable** struct which contains info array to get **Title** and **IconName** above the **textfield**
`InfoRow`  is a view where I build the title, textfield and icon using `Info.info.title`  etc...
`InfoView`  displays the `InfoRows`  with their correct contents through `ForEach`  of the `Info.info`  array. The problem remains the **TextFields** because I don't know how to manage the **Text Binding** Field

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I completely rewrote my code to try to make all my reasoning as clear as possible... I also updated my question with the new code...

Comment: I still fail to understand how you want to map an array, Info.rows, against a single object, Manager, of properties. Why does it have to be an array in the first place?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I was using `forEach`  because I thought it was the best way when I have to sort multiple data instead of repeating the code 3 times.. maybe that's the problem? Am I wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Yes I think it's better to not use ForEach since the actual data, the properties in Manager, is not an array nor are the really suited to be used as a collection.

Answer (score 0):

ForEach is a View not a loop. If you read the docs it explains identifiable data. There usually is only one object that stores arrays of model structs, eg something like this:

```
class Model: ObservableObject { // sometimes called Store
     @Published var infos: [Info] =[] 

    var shared = Model()
    var preview = Model(preview: true) // load sample data for previews
    ...
    // init/load/save code

}

struct Info: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID() // or computed var combining other lets to make a unique string
     var name: String = ""
     var address: String = ""
     var city: String = ""    
}

...
// View code 
@EnvironmentObject var model: Model // set this in App struct with .environmentObject(Model.shared) and use Model.preview in your preview code for this View file

ForEach($model.infos) { $info in
    LabeledContent("Name") {
            TextField("name", text: $info.name )
        }
```